# Correctly extending of section in Blade

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have master layout

**master.blade.php**

```
@yield('content')
```

**column.blade.php**

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
           @yield('column')
       </div>

       <div class="col-md-9">
           @yield('content')
       </div>
   </div>
@stop
```

When i am trying to extend **column.blade.php** and put my content to "content" section like this

**admin.blade.php**

```
@extends('column')

@section('column')
    content in column section
@stop

@section('content')
    content in col-md-9 div
@stop
```

I get a strange behavior. My content put in master.blade.php!!! What i am doing wrong?

If i am adding @parent i get double data (first is column.blade and after master.blade)

How can i do correctly override or extend the section?

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but I don't think you can extend twice - which is probably your issue.

Comment: @Repox you can extend as many times as you wish however using the same name for 2 yields (content in master and content in column) is asking for trouble. If i recall correctly the engine works it way up the heirachy and updates a array of named sections meaning master's content section overrides the one in column. To fix use different names.

Comment: @AbstractChaos Now I solved the problem as you say. But we want to understand why does not work as described above.

Answer (score 1):

In your `column.blade.php` file you have defined `@section('content')` and in your `admin.blade.php` file you have extended `column.blade.php` correctly.

But in your `admin.blade.php` file you have defined a new `@section('content')`. This new section overrides the `@section('content')` in your `column.blade.php` file.

What you want to do is to add `@parent` to the `@section('content')` in the `admin.blade.php` file. This will extend the content section in the column file.